# Deleting a sub-collection in Firebase -Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have tasks subcollection for every user, How can I delete tasks ,

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
   

Future<void> deleteTask() {
    return users
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection('Tasks').delete() ?? ??
        .then((value) => print("Tasks Deleted"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to delete task: $error"));
  }
```

Comment: whats the problem ? is there any error

Comment: @MajidAli You cannot invoke `delete()` on collection reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete all documents in collection or subcollection with Cloud Firestore, you can use the delete method iterating on a DocumentReference:

```dart
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> deleteAllTaskDocs() {
  return users
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection('Tasks')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            doc.reference.delete();
        });
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that:

- There is no operation that atomically deletes a collection.
- Deleting a document does not delete the documents in its subcollections.
- If your documents have dynamic subcollections, it can be hard to know what data to delete for a given path.
- Deleting a collection of more than 500 documents requires multiple batched write operations or hundreds of single deletes.